# How to filter markers on GoogleMapView using CollectionView items in IOS Swift 4

Tags: ios, google-maps, uicollectionview, swift4, marker

I have used googleMapView in my iOS application, I am placing markers in random places by doing This:

```
struct location {
    let icon: UIImage
    let latitude : CLLocationDegrees
    let longitude : CLLocationDegrees
}

class MapViewController: UIViewController,GMSMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  let locations = [
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"beautycare.png")!, latitude: 36.771873, longitude: -119.750724),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"childcare.png")!, latitude: 36.771930, longitude: -119.761352),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"carpentry.png")!, latitude: 36.772243, longitude: -119.774393),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"education.png")!, latitude: 36.772499, longitude: -119.739129),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"plumbing.png")!, latitude: 36.781273, longitude: -119.793848),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"massage.png")!, latitude: 36.781433, longitude: -119.723345),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"childcare.png")!, latitude: 36.781569, longitude: -119.830231),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"security.png")!, latitude: 36.782312, longitude: -119.767465),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"cleaning.png")!, latitude: 36.782933, longitude: -119.814373),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"beautycare.png")!, latitude: 36.783156, longitude: -119.794719),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"carpentry.png")!, latitude: 36.783873, longitude: -119.363839),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"massage.png")!, latitude: 36.784289, longitude: -119.738238),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"education.png")!, latitude: 36.793321, longitude: -119.738920),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"childcare.png")!, latitude: 36.796312, longitude: -119.749201),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"beautycare.png")!, latitude: 36.799893, longitude: -119.798301),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"plumbing.png")!, latitude: 36.803455, longitude: -119.821022),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"massage.png")!, latitude: 36.803953, longitude: -119.873910),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"carpentry.png")!, latitude: 36.804273, longitude: -119.801032),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"plumbing.png")!, latitude: 36.807721, longitude: -119.834747),
        location(icon: UIImage(named :"beautycare.png")!, latitude: 36.809213, longitude: -119.749321)]

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        for location in locations {

            let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude,location.longitude)
            marker.icon = location.icon
            marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
            marker.map = googleMapView
        }
 }
```

Now I have a horizontal collectionView in my ViewController where there are services with respective Image and service name.

Now, when I click on any item in collectionView, it should filter the icon at the locations based on the service I selected in collectionView.

Comment: filter your array with location , let newArray = locations.filter{$0.latitude == "your lattitude"}

Comment: @Vasanthan Prem Thanks for the reply. Now I am able to filter the array  to get the locations to the specific places.. But, I have to filter it using let newArray = locations.filter{return $0.icon == UIImage(named:"beautycare")}. now this gives me a new array and what I need is when I click on collectionView i need to show the markers at locations in this newArray..

Comment: clear your map view and assign new array to mapmarker in collectionview didselect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> filter your array with location ,

```
let newArray = locations.filter{$0.latitude == "your lattitude"}
```

Comment: I would be so thankful if you can share some example code snippet on how to implement that. I am beginner, so I am a bit poor in logics..